# Scrapy won't get all the text from span class

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy, but followed a tutorial and could get all the text wanted unless for just this tag:

[Text on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4oi9.png)

Inspecting it:

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGoMY.png)

so the CSS tag is ".review-date", and I've done:

country_and_date = response.css('.review-date::text').extract()

But I only get: "June 25, 2019" instead of **all text** "Reviewed in the United States on June 25, 2019"

Can someone explain to me why/help me get all the text?

Also, here is the site:
https://www.amazon.com/Acer-Display-Graphics-Keyboard-A515-43-R19L/product-reviews/B07RF1XD36/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=2&filterByStar=five_star

EDIT:

```
def parse(self,response):
    items = amazon_tutorial_items_to_scrape() #var items will store amazon_tutorial_items_to_scrape instance


    product_name = response.css('.a-text-ellipsis .a-link-normal').css('::text').extract() #when having 2 tags, use ::text in the end, else, in the tag.
    country_and_date = response.css('.review-date::text').extract()

    rating_text = response.css('.review-rating').extract()
    rate =[] 
    for x in rating_text:
        extracting_stars = Selector(text=x).xpath('//span/text()').extract_first()
        rate.append(extracting_stars)
    title = response.css('.a-text-bold span::text').extract()
    name_reviewer = response.css('.a-profile-name::text').extract()
    badge = response.css('.c7y-badge-text::text').extract()
    review = response.css('.review-text-content span::text').extract()

    items['product_name'] = product_name
    items['country_and_date'] = country_and_date
    items['rate'] = rate
    items['title'] = title
    items['name_reviewer'] = name_reviewer
    items['badge'] = badge 
    items['review'] = review

    print('******************************************')

    #writing

    yield items

    #Next page scraping
    next_page = response.css('li.a-last > a::attr(href)').extract_first() #extracting all the link
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, next_page),callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: edited, completely forgot, sorry.

Comment: Please double-check your expected results. If I call the website, I am getting: "<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date">June 25, 2019</span>". This fits to your outcome....

Comment: Hey, @AndiSchroff thanks for reaching out, I'm looking for the complete text: "Reviewed in the United States on June 25, 2019", and couldn't get it.

Comment: @usr2564301 appreciate the patience, I'm still learning, even in SO. I hope it is easier now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks your your reply. If I open the website using your link, the text including "Reviewed in the United States on " is NOT on the website. [image: screenshot]

I am not logged in into Amazon webiste. Maybe the location is not displayed, when you are not logged in?

Comment: I just doublechecked: The location is only displayed when you are logged in. You need to log in.

Comment: ok, got it. Gotta search on how to be logged in, using scrapy I guess.

Comment: I used the following code as example: https://github.com/gersmann/xing_contact_scraper